# Use command line to print number of unique words

Tags: shell-script

I have some homework:

> Find how many unique words and their count in the file alice? Print
>   the sorted unique words to a file named alice_unique. Be careful, that
>   when you split words with apostrophes they split correctly, same with
>   any other special character.

I have this so far,

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\012' < alice | sort | uniq -c > alice_unique
```

but I dont know how to keep words with special characters (',!,?,etc) together. Or how to count the number of unique words altogether.

Text File Alice (Beginning of it)

> ALICE'S ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND
>
> Lewis Carroll
>
> THE MILLENNIUM FULCRUM EDITION 3.0
>
> CHAPTER I. Down the Rabbit-Hole
>
> Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
>   bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the
>   book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in
>   it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or
>   conversation?'
>
> So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the
>   hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure
>   of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and
>   picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran
>   close by her.

Comment: Can you post some example lines from your file?  Are you ignoring capitalization?

Comment: Yes, ignoring capitalization I guess. I'll post example lines right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<alice tr -cd "[:alpha:][:space:]-'" |
  tr ' [:upper:]' '\n[:lower:]' |
  tr -s '\n' |
  sed "s/^['-]*//;s/['-]$//" |
  sort |
  uniq -c > alice_unique
```

Line by line:

- Remove everything but letters, whitespace, apostrophes and hyphens
- Turn spaces into newlines and convert uppercase to lowercase
- "Squeeze" consecutive newlines
- Strip off leading or trailing apostrophes and hyphens
- Sort the words
- Show each unique word with a count of how many times it occurred

If you're supposed to count numbers as words this is wrong.  If the text is not ASCII this may not work.  For *Alice in Wonderland* it's probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, where  is the text file:

```
awk -- '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) wc[$i] += 1}; END {for (w in wc) print w, wc[w]}' <file> | sort
```

By default, awk splits each line of input on whitespace, producing fields $1, $2, ..., up to NF, which provides a count of the number of input fields. It also iterates over all the input lines implicitly. The END tag gives a block of code to be executed after all lines are processed. Variables are not declared, and square brackets are used to reference associative arrays.

This awk program is taking each word of each line, using that word as an index into wc[], and adding to the count (which is treated as zero if not yet defined). So the for loop, and implicit outer loop over all lines, counts all the unique words (punctuation will lead to it being counted as a different word, but that's easily fixed if desired). The END block then prints out all the words and their counts.

I used a pipe to sort to put the words in order, rather than complicating the awk program. I also just removed the "-u" I had previously, as each line is going to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an AWK solution. Note that it is a basic solution
and it might need to be expanded.
For instance, if we parsed the Bible, we would need to exclude the verses
from the words.

```
{
    if (NR == 1) { 
        sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/,"")
    }

    gsub(/[,;!()*:?.]*/, "")
    
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {

        w = $i
        words[w]++
    }
} 

END {

    print length(words)
}
```

This program strips the BOM character, which if not done, makes one word 'unique'. It strips some basic punctuation marks. In the for loop, we count all the fields.

An in the end, we get the length of the array.